# Voice Recognition MIT app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am creating a voice recognition app with [MIT AppInventor](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/) that can match the voice I recorded that will activate the alarm. Problem is that I don't know how to match the voice I recorded to my voice recognition app to be able for the phone to activate the alarm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice recognition using app inventor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844322/voice-recognition-using-app-inventor)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a series of codes that save your recorded audio/speech recognizer input to a TinyDB. To do this, you create a button or something to trigger the block "call speech recognizer.get text". After that is done you place down the "After SpeechRecognizer.get text" block and inside it place the "call DB1.store value", and set the value to the variable "result" provided by "After speechrecognizer.get text". I made an example with a few other things that make it seem larger than it actually is, mainly other means of security. The screenshot is outdated, I added a few things after but they're just minor preference tweaks that have no effect on the functionality of the program. Please enjoy!
https://docs.google.com/document/d/14PunjHwjBxdyJcaKtoNydpz7U5w2FgQwPXUrRjGNqpk/edit?usp=sharing.