# Voice recognition using app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

Can android phone recognize a recorded voice using app inventor? I don't know how I can match my recorded voice to speech recognition to activate the alarm.

Answer (score 1):

In designer's view:

1. Create a button.
2. Create a speech recognizer
3. Create a text to speech

In blockers' view:

1. add a button-clicked `do block.Get speechRecognizer.getText`
2. add a speech recognizer `afterGetttingText do block.Call textToSpeech.Speak`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what app inventor is but google has an api for voice recognition.
https://cloud.google.com/speech

Comment: App inventor is a software that develops mobile app. I am trying to make a mobile app that will somehow activate an alarm using the voice which I recorded . Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

App Inventor has Speech Recognizer Component that uses Google services for Speech Recognition
The component will convert your Speech to Text

So you can compare the text output conversion for Triggering Alarm

Comment: Please Note App Inventor does not have Background Service hence you will have to start the App for Voice Recognition